# Do I need to setup an SMTP MTA for a contact us form on a VPS?

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, vps, email-server

I'm about to setup a Linode running a Centos server with a rails apps. The rails app has a contact us form. That justs send enquirys to the site owner. No other email functionality is needed

The site owner just uses his gmail email account, so no email is currently configured for the domain hosting rails app.

My question is, do I have to setup postfix on server hosting the rails app so it can send emails to the site owner or is there some other way ?

If I have to do it, am I correct in assuming I'll have to setup MX records, Sender frameworks SSL certs,etc ? :(

I'm looking for an easy way out :)

The server will have a static IP and a valid DNS entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is *NO* need for anything installed as `mailx - send and receive Internet mail` *IS* already installed on your system, this is part of any Linux distro out there, but just in case if it doesn't you can always install it separately *UNLESS* you're planning to receive emails as well and in that case you *DO* need to install SMTP MTA (such as: sendmail/postfix/etc).

Comment: Is that right ?  Whats the difference between me sending emails from Linux server and a spammer doing it ?  I thought for me to send emails the receiver mail server has to do MX lookups/ reverse lookups plus other verification before it will accept the email I've sent. This server is a VPS on the internet not a VM at home using my isp domain.

Comment: MX is only needed for incoming emails and not for outgoing.

Comment: mailx is fine, but there is *great* value in installing a local MTA that can queue mails locally before relaying them out to a smarthost. This protects you from transient issues that would otherwise cause mailx (and it's "fire and forget" stance) to lose mail.

Comment: Thanks @EEAA. I understand, but this server would be the smarthost :)

Comment: @AndyM - well then you *definitely* don't want to use mailx. A smarthost *needs* to run a real MTA.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you check out [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/) if you're not comfortable with setting up your own SMTP server.

You can [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) verify your emails as well to reduce your risk of having your email blocked.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

All you'll have to do is enter the connection information for an existing MTA. You can send email to a gmail account from a gmail account.  Google's SMTP settings can be found [here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=ts.cs&ts=1668960&from=12103&rd=1).

To see the SMTP settings in the link above, click on "I want to enable POP" and then select "Other" for your mail client.

Comment: he's looking for SMTP and your link is for POP/IMAP

Comment: You have to select POP and then select other.

Comment: How is this getting a minus?  You need to send email through an MTA, or you'll get blocked by spam filters.  Google is a valid MTA. What am I missing?

Comment: At the end of the day it's up to @AndyM, but for me personally that wouldn't be a solution as I'd prefer have my own SMTP server instead of using 3rd party and as I mentioned in mine answer most likely there is something already installed that sends out email, so this is just not needed at the first place.

Comment: If you send out email from an IP address that is from a shared hosting provider or from a dynamic IP, you'll get blocked by spam filters, sometimes they don't even make it to the Spam folder.  For a reliable solution, a trusted MTA is needed.  It doesn't have to be Gmail, but creating your own is much harder than it sounds.

Comment: you don't know if OP has a dynamic IP or not, right? Also in production environment you wouldn't want to use 3rd party services such as this, you'd want to have your own SMTP server, and SMTP server is _NOT_ that hard to set it up.

Comment: The server will have a fixed IP, it will have a valid DNS name. I've used SMTP servers before but they have all forward onto another server for relaying out to the internet. The case in my question - the server is sending direct not forwarding/relaying to some other mail server.